# ShinyDashboard - displaying more than 3 infoBoxes on the same row

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to display 4 infoBoxes (or valueBoxes, I don't really care) in the same row, and it just doesn't seem to work...

This is a working simplified version of the code, based on the shinydashbaord tutorial on Rstudio wesite (mine is using infoBoxOutputs, but I guess it doesn't matter for the formatting here):

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Info boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # infoBoxes with fill=FALSE
    fluidRow(
      infoBox("1st", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
      infoBox("2nd", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
      infoBox("3rd", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
    )
  )
)
```

which displays 3 infoBoxes in the same line. However once I add one more infoBox, it moves to a new line:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Info boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # infoBoxes with fill=FALSE
    fluidRow(
      infoBox("1st", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
      infoBox("2nd", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
      infoBox("3rd", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
      infoBox("4th", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card")),
    )
  )
)
```

I also tried using columns - the boxes were then displays on the same row, but were distorted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the 'width' parameter?

Comment: `infoBox("1st", 10 * 2, icon = icon("credit-card"), width = 3)` try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is what I was looking for:

In the server.R:
set the value boxes with width = 3:

```
output$infoBox1 <- renderValueBox({..., valueBox(...,width = 3)})
```

In the UI.R: 
put 4 columns with the valueBoxOutputs, in this manner:

```
column( 3,valueBoxOutput("infoBox1", width = 12))
```

Answer (score 7):

Within a `fluidRow` from `shiny`, we know that it has a max column width of 12.

Taking a look at the `infoxBox` function:

```
infoBox(title, value = NULL, subtitle = NULL,
  icon = shiny::icon("bar-chart"), color = "aqua", width = 4,
  href = NULL, fill = FALSE)
}
```

we see that the setting for width is `width = 4`.

To get your desired 4 infoBoxes fitted on one row, just set `width = 3`.

---

An explicit example for all intents and purposes:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    infoBox("test", value=1, width=3),
    infoBox("test", value=2, width=3),
    infoBox("test", value=3, width=3),
    infoBox("test", value=4, width=3)
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: I tried this before already (forgot to mention in the post), and again now - it doesn't work... Still 3 boxes displayed per line.

Comment: @KeshetE Try my example within my added edits. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Maybe it's different when building the infoBox in the server side?

Comment: Excellent explanation. Used your explanation to figure out how to fit 3 `box()` components on the same line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(                      ##Change for fluidPage
     mainPanel(width = 12,        ##HERE 
      infoBox("test", value=1, width=3),
      infoBox("test", value=2, width=3),
      infoBox("test", value=3, width=3),
      infoBox("test", value=4, width=3)
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This seems to work for me. My app had the same issue.